# Show Top 3 Values in Excel (Non VBA )

Tags: excel

I have two column A and B, A is item's name, B is value.  I could use Large function to return the top 3 values from B and use Vlook to return what is the item's name corresponding to these top 3 values. EXCEPT, when there are repeated values, Vlook up will not work as expected.

I understand this because Vlook only return the value of first found.

Anyway to overcome this problem will be appreciated

Comment: You could use Excel's [COUNTIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx) function to calculate the number of cells larger than the cell in question. This would result in a ranking to select the cells in the top three positions.

Comment: Show some sample data and what you expect the result to be.

Comment: Tell us how do you want to handle when top 3 matches more than one item's name? Do you need all matching items returned or just one? As @DickKusleika mentioned please give us example data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than doing the easy thing and just sorting the list and taking the top three.

You can use the COUNTIF function to break ties arbitrarily:

```
=A2+(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,"="&A2)*0.00000000001)
```

[image: e1]

```
=LARGE($B$2:$B$6,F2)
```

[image: e2]

```
=VLOOKUP(G2,$B$2:$C$6,2,FALSE)
```

[image: e3]

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank everyone for the help.  The solution provided by Stepan1010 works perfect.  The result I do not use the sort function because I want to create something like Dashboard

Comment: In addition, I replace the countif with ROW()*0.00000001

Answer (score 4):

You can use an **Autofilter**, and for the column under test select
Number Filters --> Top 10... and enter 3 in the Dialog field asking for the Top-N to display

[image]